# Javascript how to compare mongoose Date with a String

Tags: javascript, mongodb, date, mongoose

so I ran into this little problem and I don't know how to solve it. I have two dates, one that comes from a Python script that arrives as a String, and one that comes from a MongoDB object. I need to compare them but the date coming from MongoDB seems to have a strange format that doesn't allow me to do so. This is an example of the dates formats:

```
String: 29/12/22 15:00
Object: Wed Dec 28 2022 15:00:00 GMT+0100 (hora estándar de Europa central)
```

From this I can easily transform the String coming from Python to a Date object, but what should I do with the MongoDB object to be able to compare them?

Comment: Are you sure? When you say "comes from a MongoDB object" then it seems to be already a `Date` object and you don't need to convert it. "Wed Dec 28 2022 15:00:00 GMT+0100 (hora estándar de Europa central)" is just the way how your terminal **displays** it.

Comment: Hi @Wernfried Domscheit. I don't understand why, but despite being this data saved as a Date in the model, executing `console.log(typeof date2)` results on `Object`

Comment: Then it is a date. `typeof new Date()` also returns `Object`

Comment: Oh, Okay. Didn't know, thanks for the explanation! I solved it using moments as explained below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the information the value from MongoDB (here: `date2`) is not a string, it is a `Date` object. Thus you need to convert only the value from Python (here: `date1`):

```
if ( moment(date1, 'DD/MM/YY HH:mm').toDate() > date2 ) {
   console.log('true')
} else {
   console.log('false')
}
```

Or, if you prefer to work with `Moment` objects:

```
moment(date1, 'DD/MM/YY HH:mm').isAfter(moment(date2))
```

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to explain it!

Answer (score 1):

You can use momentjs to format dates in javascript.
He is an Example:

```js
let date1 = "25/12/22 15:00"
let date2 = "Wed Dec 27 2022 15:00:00 GMT+0100"

if(moment(date1,'DD/MM/YY HH:mm') > new Date(date2)){
  console.log('True')
} else {
    console.log('false')
}
```

```html
<script type = "text/JavaScript" src = " https://MomentJS.com/downloads/moment.js"></script>
```

Comment: it is not showing true value for date1 = 27/12/22

Comment: I think for moment.js you should better use [isAfter/isBefore](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/query/)

Comment: @Sammed In case `date1 = 27/12/22` as it is same date as `date2` I guess you should use the operator `>=` instead of `>` at `if` condition if you want a `True` in this situation

Comment: still not working for me

Answer (score 1):

Here's a very longhand method: pass the mongo date as a string, split it into its components, and rebuild it. Here, it's rebuilt to the same format as your Python script produces.

```js
function convert(mongoDateString) {
          const monthAr = ["", "Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec"];
          const mongoDateAr = mongoDateString.split(" ");
          const dayNo = mongoDateAr[2];
          const monthNo = monthAr.indexOf(mongoDateAr[1]);
          const yearNo = mongoDateAr[3];
          const time = mongoDateAr[4].substring(0, mongoDateAr[4].length - 3);
          return dayNo + "/" + monthNo + "/" + yearNo + " " + time;
        }

        let thisDateString = "Wed Dec 28 2022 15:00:00 GMT+0100 (hora estándar de Europa central)"
        console.log(convert(thisDateString ))
```

Comment: Why do you reinvent the wheel? There are many ready-to-use libraries (e.g. [Moment.js](https://momentjs.com/docs/), [Luxon](https://moment.github.io/luxon/index.html#/?id=luxon), [Day.js](https://day.js.org/en/)) which do this in a single line.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer! Seems like doing it with moments it's pretty easier, take a look at the answer if you can. Anyways, thanks for taking your time searching for a solution

Comment: Sure there are many libraries, with varying overhead, but I thought the original poster might like to see how date (and other) strings can be manipulated with splitting, as this was something he appeared not to be aware of. When I started, I found this more educative than plugging in a library. But I understand your point.